# ¿Como transformar los días, horas y minutos acumulados, a formato de días, horas de 24 y minutos de 60 en C#?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Por ejemplo, he sumado todos los días, horas y minutos:

```
int días=71;
int horas=90;
int minutos=653;
```

Lo que deseo, teniendo estos valores, mediante de algun calculo que se convertir en valores que son con horas no superando las 24, con minutos no superando los 60. 
por ejemplo, si los minutos pasan los 60, los restantes acumularselo a la hora, y si la hora supera las 24, lo faltante pasárselos a los días.
obteniendo un resultado similar como esto:

```
int diaTransformado=75;
int horaTransformada=4;
int minutoTransformado= 53;
```

No se si me explique bien, pero necesito saber si hay alguna función o calculo que me lo permita hacer,cual y como sería?

Comment: tenes un problema matematico o de codigo? porque la matematica de esto es trivial. Podrias mostrar el codigo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: el resultado esperado es donde dice diaTransformado,horaTransformada, minutosTransformado.

Comment: aquí hay un ejemplo matematico de como hacerlo para horas y minutos, http://es.wikihow.com/convertir-minutos-a-horas
pero no se si en C# existe alguna función que lo haga directo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un `TimeSpan` al que le pases los dias, horas minutos y segundos en su constructor

```
int días = 71;
int horas = 90;
int minutos = 653;

var ts = new TimeSpan(días, horas, minutos, 0);

int diaTransformado = ts.Days; // 75
int horaTransformada = ts.Hours; // 4
int minutoTransformado = ts.Minutes; // 53
```

Answer (score 2):

O puedes intentar asi :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int dias=71;
        int horas=90;
        int minutos=653;

        int horas_minutos = (int) minutos/60; 
        minutos = minutos%60;

        horas = horas + horas_minutos;

        int dias_horas = (int)horas/24;
        horas = horas % 24;

        dias = dias + dias_horas;

        Console.WriteLine("Dias : {0}, Horas : {1}, Minutos : {2}", dias, horas, minutos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aún no se muy bien como lo desee pero si lo que quieres es controlarlo tu mismo puedes crear una función para calcularlos.

```
void calcularFecha(int dia, int hora, int minuto)
{
    while(minuto <= 60);
    {
        minuto -= 60;
        hora++;
    }

    while(hora <= 24){
        hora -= 24;
        dia++;
    }


    string.Format("{0} días {1} horas {2} minutos", dias, horas, minutos);
}
```

Con while puedes validar en ciclos para restar y sumar su consecutivo hasta que estos tengan su rango de tiempo.

Y con string.Format puedes mostrarlos como lo desees.

Answer (score 1):

Hola la siguiente es una opción sencilla que resuelve el problema

```
horas = horas + (int)(minutos / 60);
minutos = minutos % 60;
dias = dias + (int)(horas / 24)
horas = horas % 24
```

la idea de empezar de abajo para arriba, porque si calculo primero días, puede que los minutos generen horas suficiente para contabilizar un nuevo día y en los días no se vean reflejadas.